# Disable caching of Web API responses

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to disable browser caching of all the Web API responses across all the clients. Even though I can use libraries like [CacheOutput](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Strathweb.CacheOutput.WebApi2/) or [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow) as suggested in [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx) but my requirement is not that complex. I just want to disable caching of all the Web API responses and do not need any custom control over it.

- How do I do that in ASP.NET Web API 2?
- Which headers do I need to set? `'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'?`
- Is ETag, Last-Modified, etc needed? Or maybe any other response headers??
- It need to be implemented in a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers), right?

Comment: please can someone help me on this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header.
Implement it as delegating-Handler and make sure your header is applied (with MS Owin Implementation hook up on `OnSendingHeaders()`. I'm using it here [OnSendingHeaders() Example](https://github.com/StefanOssendorf/SecurityHeadersMiddleware/blob/master/src/OwinContrib.SecurityHeaders/ContentSecurityPolicyMiddleware.cs)).

Comment: Note for .NET Core development, override `OnActionExecuted` function and place `Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` in it. Remember to leave the `base.OnActionExecuted(context);` in that function to ensure that it handles the commands properly.